# Unistall error using home-brew -> error using brew prune

Tags: homebrew, iterm2, iterm, homebrew-cask

I have Paste installed and want to uninstall it, currently running macOS High Sierra.
I have tried using the `$ brew uninstall Paste` and it gets returned with `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/paste`.

After that I used `$ brew update` of which everything is up-to-date.

So after that I used `$ brew doctor` which returned

```
 Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W3
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W6
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuProN-W3
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuProN-W6
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuStd-W8
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuStdN-W8
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMaruPro-W4
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMaruProN-W4
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinPro-W3
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinPro-W6
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinProN-W3
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinProN-W6
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraginoSansGB-W3
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraginoSansGB-W6
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuGo-Bold
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuGo-Medium
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuMin-Demibold
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuMin-Medium
```

However, when I try and use `$ brew prune` I get returned with
`Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W3`

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run:

```
brew uninstall paste
```

---

You're getting the error: **No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/paste`when`brew uninstall Past** because there are no **brew formulae** installed or in the official **Homebrew repository** named **paste**.

```
brew install paste
Error: No available formula with the name "paste"
```

I guess you've installed it using cask:

```
brew cask install paste
```

If you try to uninstall it using **brew** you'll get that error:

```
brew uninstall Paste
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/paste
```

To uninstall **paste** simply use **brew cask** instead:

```
brew cask uninstall paste
```